# Extremely Slow Query which contains multiple Sub-Queries SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, optimization, sql-server-2008-r2, subquery, query-optimization

I am working on a query that does an audit of a form. There are several pages worth of questions to audit. When the form is filled out the answers are stored in two tables in the following fashion:

```
Table 1: smsmir.obsv OBS
EPISODE NO | FORM USAGE | QUEST      | ANSWER | ...
123456789  | ADMISSION  | QUESTION 1 | YES    | ...
123456789  | ADMISSION  | QUESTION 2 | 150    | ...
...

Table 2: smsdss.QOC_vst_summ QOC
EPISODE NO | HT IND | WT IND | ADV DIR | ...
123456789  |    1   |   1    |     0   | ...
...
```

Table 1: `smsmir.obsv OBS` stores information in a vector, so for each question there is another row. Table 2: `smsdss.QOC_vst_summ QOC` stores answers in a row, so there is only one row per visit. Table 3 is the same, there is only one row per visit id.

My query starts off by collecting `VISIT IDS` that get stored in a table and then passed off to the next set in order to answer some questions. The reason I pull the visit ids from this other table is because that is where the Visit start and end date is stored. That table looks something like this:

```
Table 3: smsdss.BMH_PLM_PtAcct_V PAV
EPISODE NO | ADM DATE   | ...
123456789  | 2013-08-01 | ...
...
```

My desired output which I do get is something of the following:

```
EPISODE NO | QUESTION 1  | QUESTION 2 | HT IND | WT IND | ADV DIR | ...
123456789  |   1         | 1          |    1   |    1   |    0    | ...
...
```

In the above table the 1 would represent that the question was answered using a case statement and 0 would indicate not answered. The query has been re-written and is now producing correct results, but is horrendously slow, to get back 40 records took 53 minutes 36 seconds. As the query is currently unfinished only 7 columns are returning, I have to expand this to have a total of 65 columns.

The reason I have the sub-queries is that the answers are stored in a vector, each row is a question and answer but since I want to show the answers and questions in columns I do a sub-query. Is there a better way to speed this up?

Here is the query:

```
-- THIS QUERY WILL PERFORM AN AUDIT OF THE ADMISSION ASSESSMENT AND
-- OTHER REQUIRED QUESTIONS BY NURSING INFORMATICS
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
-- VARIABLE DECLARATION AND INITIALIZATION. BY DECLARING A START AND
-- END DATE A USER CAN SIMPLY CHANGE THOSE PARAMETERS AND AUDIT ALL 
-- INPATIENT ADMISSION ASSESSMENTS FOR THAT TIME PERIOD
DECLARE @SD DATETIME
DECLARE @ED DATETIME

SET @SD = '2013-08-01'
SET @ED = '2013-08-01'

-- QUERY 1
-- THIS QUERY CREATES A TABLE THAT WILL HOUSE ALL VISIT ID NUMBERS THAT
-- ARE GOING TO BE INCLUDED INSIDE OF THE ADMISSION ASSESSMENT AUDIT
-- TABLE DECLARATION ##################################################
DECLARE @T1 TABLE (
  VISIT_ID VARCHAR(20))

-- ####################################################################
-- THESE ARE THE ITEMS THAT ARE GOING TO BE INSERTED INTO THE TABLE
INSERT INTO @T1
-- COLUMN SELECTION
SELECT A.PtNo_Num
-- DB(S) USED
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT PTNO_NUM
        FROM   smsdss.BMH_PLM_PtAcct_V
        WHERE  Adm_Date BETWEEN @SD AND @ED
               AND Plm_Pt_Acct_Type = 'I') A

--+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
--+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++//
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
-- QUERY TWO. THIS QUERY WILL TAKE THE VISIT ID'S FROM QUERY 1 AND RUN
-- THEM THROUGH A SET OF RULES TO DECIDE WHEATHER OR NOT THE ADDMISISON
-- ASSESSMENT WAS PROPERLY DONE
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
-- COLUMN SELECTION
SELECT DISTINCT OBS.episode_no  AS [VISIT ID]
                -- CASE STATEMENT, IF PREFERRED LANGUAGE IS NOT 'NULL' THEN CONSIDER
                -- THIS COMPLETE AND SCORE 1 ELSE CONSIDER INCOMPLETE AND SCORE 0
                ,
                CASE
                  WHEN QOC.prim_lng IS NOT NULL THEN 1
                  ELSE 0
                END             AS [PREF LANG COMPLETE?],
                QOC.ht_chtd_ind AS [HT IND],
                QOC.wt_chtd_ind AS [WT IND],
                QOC.adv_dir_ind AS [ADV DIRECTIVE]
                -- A SEPERATE SELECT STATEMENT IS USED HERE BECAUSE RESULTS OF THE
                -- ADMISSION CONSENT ARE STORED IN A VECTOR, SO IT IS NECESSARY TO
                -- MAKE A SELECTION FROM THAT LIST, HERE A VALUE OF 1 = YES AND 
                -- 0 = NO
                ,
                CASE
                  WHEN OBS.episode_no NOT IN (SELECT episode_no
                                              FROM   smsmir.obsv
                                              WHERE  form_usage = 'Admission') THEN 0
                  ELSE 1
                END             AS [ADMIT ASSESSMENT DONE],
                CASE
                  WHEN OBS.episode_no NOT IN (SELECT episode_no
                                              FROM   smsmir.obsv
                                              WHERE  form_usage = 'Admission'
                                                     AND obsv_cd_ext_name = 'Admission consent signed:') THEN 0
                  ELSE 1
                END             AS [ADMIT CONSENT SIGNED?]
-- DB(S) USED ---------------------------------------------------------
FROM   smsmir.obsv OBS
       JOIN smsdss.QOC_vst_summ QOC
         ON OBS.episode_no = QOC.episode_no
       JOIN @T1 T1
         ON OBS.episode_no = T1.VISIT_ID
-- FILTERS ------------------------------------------------------------
WHERE  T1.VISIT_ID = OBS.episode_no
GROUP  BY OBS.episode_no,
          QOC.prim_lng,
          QOC.ht_chtd_ind,
          QOC.wt_chtd_ind,
          QOC.adv_dir_ind,
          OBS.obsv_cd_ext_name
--#####################################################################
-- END REPORT ...[]...[]...[]
```

You will notice that I am using a `NOT IN`clause, the reason is that if a question was not asked or answered, there will be no record, not even a `NULL`, so if I do not use that, person could have all other things done but if not that particular item, then they are excluded from the final result set.

If I need to make a clarification please let me know.

** QUERY Actual Execution Plan XML **
[query exec actual xml](https://app.box.com/s/stlhmh8j5m8tmu7yopds)

Thank you

Comment: Please upload the XML for the actual (not estimated) execution plan somewhere.

Comment: Will do, it will take about 30 minutes or so for it to run with in order to show two of the questions that require subquery.

Comment: In that case before you do that try replacing the table variable `@T1` with `CREATE TABLE #T1(VISIT_ID VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY)`. It might help but at least shouldn't hinder.

Comment: @MartinSmith trying that now in a separate query window

Comment: Also you mention  the answers are stored in two tables but then show us three, and the names of the tables and columns don't correspond to those used in the query. And it is not clear how the desired results correspond to the example data. If you provide more extensive example data and results you will likely get a better answer.

Comment: I will make those corrections, there are two tables with answers, and a third that gets used only to generate the list of visit id's.

Comment: So does `QOC_vst_summ QOC` only have one row per `EPISODE NO` or can it have multiple?

Comment: It can have only one, I apologize, I will explain the structure of the tables in the question.

Comment: Just finished took 58 minutes, plan has been added to question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`smsmir.obsv` is a view that `UNION`-s a 155,569,000 row table and a 15,375,000 row one.

The execution plan shows that these tables are scanned 42 times.

The vast majority of this is because of the default poor cardinality estimates for table variables meaning an inappropriate choice of nested loops. Replacing with a `#temp` table should solve that issue.

Also using a `PIVOT` technique instead of individual sub queries can reduce this further. There may be additional optimisations that can be applied in terms of adding missing indexes but can you try this and let me know the timings and execution plan?

```
DECLARE @SD DATETIME = '2013-08-01';
DECLARE @ED DATETIME = '2013-08-01';

CREATE TABLE #T1
  (
     VISIT_ID VARCHAR(20) UNIQUE CLUSTERED
  )

INSERT INTO #T1
SELECT DISTINCT PTNO_NUM
FROM   smsdss.BMH_PLM_PtAcct_V
WHERE  Adm_Date BETWEEN @SD AND @ED
       AND Plm_Pt_Acct_Type = 'I'
OPTION (RECOMPILE);

WITH OBS
     AS (SELECT episode_no,
                MAX(CASE
                      WHEN form_usage = 'Admission' THEN 1
                    END) AS [ADMIT ASSESSMENT DONE],
                MAX(CASE
                      WHEN form_usage = 'Admission'
                           AND obsv_cd_ext_name = 'Admission consent signed:' THEN 1
                    END) AS [ADMIT CONSENT SIGNED?]
         FROM   smsmir.obsv
         WHERE form_usage = 'Admission' 
         GROUP  BY episode_no)
SELECT OBS.episode_no                         AS [VISIT ID],
       CASE
         WHEN QOC.prim_lng IS NOT NULL THEN 1
         ELSE 0
       END                                    AS [PREF LANG COMPLETE?],
       QOC.ht_chtd_ind                        AS [HT IND],
       QOC.wt_chtd_ind                        AS [WT IND],
       QOC.adv_dir_ind                        AS [ADV DIRECTIVE],
       ISNULL(OBS.[ADMIT ASSESSMENT DONE], 0) AS [ADMIT ASSESSMENT DONE],
       ISNULL(OBS.[ADMIT CONSENT SIGNED?], 0) AS [ADMIT CONSENT SIGNED?]
FROM   smsdss.QOC_vst_summ QOC
       JOIN #T1
         ON #T1.VISIT_ID = QOC.episode_no
       LEFT JOIN OBS
         ON OBS.episode_no = QOC.episode_no 

DROP TABLE #T1
```

Comment: I will try this now, for some reason I was never notified that you posted an answer when I came home from class lastnight, going to run now and will post results.

Comment: Ok this worked really fast (relative to what I had, 0:4:56:00), but when a record has no results I get a null value for the VISIT ID instead of the actual ID like 123456789. It is very important to get the ID numbers especially where there are 0's present as we want to investigate why things were not done. So if we can fix that, then this will get marked answered and you get the points. Here is the new Actual Execution XML https://app.box.com/s/stlhmh8j5m8tmu7yopds

Comment: @MCP_infiltrator - Oh yes. Instead of `SELECT OBS.episode_no` you need `SELECT #T1.VISIT_ID`

Comment: @MCP_infiltrator - Will your full query only ever be interested in rows `WHERE form_usage = 'Admission'` or once all the desired columns are added will it need to look at other rows?

Comment: I changed the episode_no to #T1.visit_id just outside the WITH, it is running now. My query will eventually look at another form. This query running in 5 to 10 minutes if perfectly fine.

Comment: That did it, got the VISIT_ID, thank you so much for your help, you showed me a lot of new things, I can now go ahead and add in the other 55 columns, might need some optimization then. Thanks again for all the help. Will mark answered and deliver points.

Comment: It says I can award my Bounty in 5 hours.

Comment: @MCP_infiltrator - Thanks. You will need to remove the `WHERE form_usage = 'Admission'` when you add those other cases then. At the moment the execution plan suggests adding a missing index with `87%` impact but wait and see what (if anything) it recommends once the whole query is finished.

Comment: For some reason the only column that does not work is the [ACCPT PAIN LVL IDENT] I checked the table and the question is there, any ideas?

Comment: What `CASE` expression are you using for that column?

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to hit the table again, you already have the data. aggregate it.

```
DECLARE @SD DATETIME
DECLARE @ED DATETIME

SET @SD = '2013-08-01'
SET @ED = '2013-08-01'

DECLARE @T1 TABLE (
  VISIT_ID VARCHAR(20))

INSERT INTO @T1
SELECT A.PtNo_Num
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT PTNO_NUM
        FROM   smsdss.BMH_PLM_PtAcct_V
        WHERE  Adm_Date BETWEEN @SD AND @ED
           AND Plm_Pt_Acct_Type = 'I') A

SELECT DISTINCT OBS.episode_no  AS [VISIT ID],
            CASE
              WHEN QOC.prim_lng IS NOT NULL THEN 1
              ELSE 0
            END             AS [PREF LANG COMPLETE?],
            QOC.ht_chtd_ind AS [HT IND],
            QOC.wt_chtd_ind AS [WT IND],
            QOC.adv_dir_ind AS [ADV DIRECTIVE],
            max(CASE
              WHEN   form_usage = 'Admission' THEN 1
              ELSE 0
            END)             AS [ADMIT ASSESSMENT DONE],
            max(CASE
              WHEN   form_usage = 'Admission' AND obsv_cd_ext_name = 'Admission consent signed:' THEN 1
              ELSE 0
            END )            AS [ADMIT CONSENT SIGNED?]
FROM   smsmir.obsv OBS
   JOIN smsdss.QOC_vst_summ QOC
     ON OBS.episode_no = QOC.episode_no
   JOIN @T1 T1
     ON OBS.episode_no = T1.VISIT_ID
WHERE  T1.VISIT_ID = OBS.episode_no
GROUP  BY OBS.episode_no,
      QOC.prim_lng,
      QOC.ht_chtd_ind,
      QOC.wt_chtd_ind,
      QOC.adv_dir_ind,
      OBS.obsv_cd_ext_name
```